# FCM works only in 'development' builds (Xcode), not on 'production' (TestFlight etc.)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have a simple Python script that sends a push notification to my Firebase service which should send the payload over APNs for the user device to receive it. However, there came an issue:

When my app is installed through the wire (like from Xcode directly), my app is able to receive the notification.
However, I can no longer receive notifications when the app is downloaded from TestFlight.

I notice how my app the first scenario (Xcode) is in the "development" state and the second (TestFlight) in the "production" state. Since the "development" app receives notifications successfully and the "production" app does not, does this mean that the FCM is sending my payload through `api.sandbox.push.apple.com` instead of `api.push.apple.com`?

What should I do so that FCM sends my payload to my "production" apps on TestFlight?

Here is the Python script that sends the notification to FCM:

```
import sys
import uuid
from datetime import datetime, timezone

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, messaging

# no need for an url here if your credentials already contain the project id.
cred = credentials.Certificate(
    '/home/pi/Desktop/taiwaneew-firebase-adminsdk-odl9d-222bd18a4e.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()

def send_data(ins, sec):

    # Create data record
    id = str(uuid.uuid1())
    data = {
        'id': id,
        'eventTime': datetime.now(timezone.utc),
        'intensity': ins,  # String
        'seconds': sec,  # int
    }
    # Send data
    db.collection('taipei').document(id).set(data)
    print("db upload done.")

    # Create message
    if int(ins[0]) >= 4:
        head = "〔 緊急地震速報 〕"
    else:
        head = "〔 地震預警 〕"
    message = messaging.Message(
        notification = messaging.Notification(
            title = head,
            body = "["+ins+"] 級地震，"+str(sec)+"秒後抵達。\n【趴下、掩護、穩住】"
        ),
       topic = "eg"+ins[0] if int(ins[0])<=4 else "eg4"
    )

    # Send message
    response = messaging.send(message)
    print("Successfully sent message to",message.topic,":", response)

def main():
    # Invoke the function to send data to Firebase
    send_data(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Information:
I've already set the APNs Environment in the Entitlements file to "production" before exporting to TestFlight.
I've correctly installed both the "production" and the "development" certificates of APNs on the Firebase dashboard.